# Constant constructor and Function in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want onPressed it print a text, but it throw an error.

**Invalid constant value**

Why i can't use onPressed when using const? Can someone explain? Sorry i'm newbie.

```
 const IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.search,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        tooltip: 'Search',
        onPressed: () => print('Hello'),
      )
```

Comment: `() => print('Hello')` is not a constant.

Comment: See my note at https://stackoverflow.com/a/69214531/: Allowing lambdas to be `const` wouldn't be free.

Answer (score 8):

You can, however anonymous functions cannot be `const` in dart. Everything passed into your `IconButton` needs to be `const` in order for `IconButton` to be `const`. That said, standalone functions and static functions can be used as `const`:

```dart
// should be a standalone function (or a static function)
void hello() {
  print('Hello');
}
```

And then you can use `IconButton` as `const`:

```dart
 const IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.search,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        tooltip: 'Search',
        onPressed: hello,
      )
```

Comment: The function hello must be const right?

Comment: The hello function will be treated as `const` so long as it is a standalone function (top-level function) or a static function. If it is defined as a (non-static) method of a class, it will not be treated as `const`.

Comment: Your answer is an absolute game changer for me: now I can rewrite my lambdas into standalone functions and convert half of the `final`-s in my project into `const`-s. Huge thanks to you!

Comment: @ArthurKhazbs glad I could help. I am hoping that the dart team will eventually implement [constant function literals](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1048) which would eliminate the need for this workaround.

Answer (score 0):

```
Read Dart official Documentation [const modifier][1]
when we use const key 
const IconButton(             //Here you are use const keyword
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.search,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        tooltip: 'Search',
        onPressed: () => print('Hello'), //error show here: Invalid constant value.
      )
    

Use this after Remove Const key modifier prefect work onPress
IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.search,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        tooltip: 'Search',
        onPressed: () => print('Hello'),
      )


  [1]: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/GtkKeyHelper/modifierShift-constant.html
```